# Javascript/Ajax error help in Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, ajax, internet-explorer

I'm building an e-commerce site for a client, and for some reason in Internet Explorer when I click the add to cart button, the shopping cart messes up the quantities added into the cart. I think for some reason IE is refreshing the page, causing the quantities to double, I just can't figure out how to fix it. I would greatly appreciate any suggestions!

An example of what I'm talking about can be found here:

http://tcatvs.com/?p=361

Then add one of the products to cart and click the mycart image at the top right and you'll see what I'm talking about.

Thanks guys!

Comment: i saw the link, but am too lazy to debug through all the javascript, but I would love to see what the reason turns out to be

Comment: That is very interesting, are you adding a default value of `1` to your shopping cart?  So when you add something to the cart, you are actually increasing the quantity to 2?

Comment: The page is reporting JavaScript errors on the calls to jQuery().livequery(), so I would start there.

Comment: Please specify the version(s) of IE that you're having trouble with. (IE sucks, but IE6 sucks a whole lot more than IE8)

Answer (score 0):

You have a syntactic error in `wp-e-commerce.js`, on line 240:

```
var container_offset = {'500'};
```